# -bash: ./radiobot cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, arm64, shoutcast, debian-stretch, armbian

I'm having trouble running a program
this error when running the program

./radiobot `-bash: ./radiobot: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

And I checked the file, it turns out that the error is on the machine type, the program requires an `x86-64` machine, while my armbian linux machine is `aarch64`

When I check with this program `file radiobot` the result is:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,
for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, 
BuildID[sha1] =c67539ec4f37bbb5d61546fade0a8b7bf2ee4659, 
stripped
```

And here are my server specs:

```
Linux localhost 5.1.0-rc1-aml-s905 
#5.84 SMP PREEMPT 
Tue May 7 11:18:59 MSK 2019 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Until now I have not found the package that the program needs to install, please help, maybe there is a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to run this cause architecture of this binary file is different from your host operating system, so basically options are:

1. get binary compiled for your architecture
2. change your host OS
3. keep your current OS and try to run that binary in a Docker container

Comment: I agree, because the program I want to run doesn't support the OS I have, so the alternative is I have to change my OS to amd, thanks.